# How lose focus of TextFiled when tapped on a button?

Tags: react-native, onblur, touchableopacity

I have a `TextInput` and `TouchableOpacity` inside `ScrollView` like follows,

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}>
     <TextInput
        placeholder='Text'
        value={this.state.value}
        onChangeText={value => this.setState({ value })}
        onBlur={() => console.log('TextInput lost it's focus)}
     />
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('This Onpress action opens a modal')}>
         <Text>Tap Here</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
</ScrollView>
```

After typing data in `TextInput` If I tap on `TouchableOpacity` then `Modal` opens as per login(Which I didn't mention here). After closing the `Modal`, Still the `TextInput` is in focus.

But I want the `TextInput` to lose focus as soon as I tapped on `TouchableOpacity`. `onBlur` function is getting called if I tap any where else other than `ToucahbleOpacity`.

How can I make `TextField` lose focus when tapped on `TouchableOpacity`?

Note: I cannot use references since I am using `Redux Form` where there are number of fields other than mentioned above and these fields may vary screen to screen dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `ref="input"` on `TextInput` and call `this.refs.input.blur()` when you click `TouchableOpacity`. Something like:

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}>
     <TextInput
        ref="input"
        placeholder='Text'
        value={this.state.value}
        onChangeText={value => this.setState({ value })}
        onBlur={() => console.log('TextInput lost it's focus)}
     />
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
         this.refs.input.blur(); //<-- here blur the TextInput
         console.log('This Onpress action opens a modal');
     }}>
         <Text>Tap Here</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
</ScrollView>
```

**EDIT:**
In case you are using `Redux Form` you have to use a callback function in `ref` and then call `ReactDOM.findDOMNode` to get the `TextInput`.Something like:

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}>
     <TextInput
        ref={(input) => { this.input = input; }}
        placeholder='Text'
        value={this.state.value}
        onChangeText={value => this.setState({ value })}
        onBlur={() => console.log('TextInput lost it's focus)}
     />
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
         ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.input).blur(); //<-- here blur the TextInput
         console.log('This Onpress action opens a modal');
     }}>
         <Text>Tap Here</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I cannot use reference since I am using `Redux Form` where there are number of fields other than mentioned above and these fields may vary screen to screen dynamically.

Comment: Do I have to give same `this.input` for all fields in the form?

Comment: @Mighty Much better create an array of this.input I think

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using functional component so you can achieve this by taking a ref and by using useRef hook.

**Example**

```
const componentName = ({ params }) => {
  const textInputRef = useRef(); // initialising ref hook

  return (
    <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps={'handled'}>
      <TextInput
        ref={textInputRef} // passing ref to textinput
        placeholder="Text"
        value={this.state.value}
        onChangeText={value => this.setState({ value })}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          textInputRef.current.blur(); //<-- by taking ref calling blur function of textinput.
          console.log('This Onpress action opens a modal');
        }}
      >
        <Text>Tap Here</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

Comment: I cannot use reference since I am using `Redux Form` where there are number of fields other than mentioned above and these fields may vary screen to screen dynamically.